# How do I make Javascript files work in a Typescript tsup bundle?

Tags: javascript, typescript, turborepo, tsup

I am trying to build a tsup bundle that contains both Javascript (.js) and Typescript (.tsx). [According to their docs](https://tsup.egoist.dev/#what-can-it-bundle), that is possible.

When I build with the `tsup` command, I get the following error message:

> rc/index.tsx(7,15): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file
> for module './Test'.

Here is a sandbox MVP: https://shorturl.at/fyOY3

How do I make it build without errors?

---

**EDIT:**

I was able to make the above error go away by adding the following to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "allowJs": true,
  "checkJs": false
}
```

However, now a new error message appears:

> TypeError: a.default.createContext is not a function

I think it is related to how the bundler handles `styled-components` in the monorepo.